# How to bind JSON response to Models in ASP MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, rest

So I'm new to the ASP/.NET/C# game, so would definitely appreciate any help you might be able to offer me. I've currently got a Controller called "ProjectController.cs" that has an action "Index" which is supposed to pass a list of "projects" to the view. I've gone ahead and created the controller, the action, the API call and the view. However, per the screenshots provided - I am running into an error with the API call itself - I'm attempting to return a list of models to the controller to be passed to the view. I am doing this through by loading a JSON response from the [http://10000ft.com api](https://www.10000ft.com/plans/reference/api-documentation/projects#top). Any ideas why I am continually getting jammed up when trying to create/validate new project objects against the model?

ProjectController.cs:

```
namespace MVCProject1.Controllers
{
    public class ProjectController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Project
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Models.Project> projects = APICalls.GetAllProjects();
            return View(projects);
        }
    }
}
```

Project Controller / Index Action View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Project Index";
}
@model IEnumerable<MVCProject1.Models.Project>

@foreach (var project in Model)
{
    @project.name <br />
}
```

ProjectModel.cs:

```
namespace MVCProject1.Models
{
    public class Project
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public bool archived { get; set; }
        public object archived_at { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string guid { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public object parent_id { get; set; }
        public object phase_name { get; set; }
        public string project_code { get; set; }
        public string secureurl { get; set; }
        public string secureurl_expiration { get; set; }
        public int settings { get; set; }
        public int timeentry_lockout { get; set; }
        public string ends_at { get; set; }
        public string starts_at { get; set; }
        public object deleted_at { get; set; }
        public string created_at { get; set; }
        public string updated_at { get; set; }
        public bool use_parent_bill_rates { get; set; }
        public string thumbnail { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public bool has_pending_updates { get; set; }
        public string client { get; set; }
        public string project_state { get; set; }

    }
}
```

APICalls.cs:

```
namespace MVCProject1
{
    public class APICalls
    {
        private const string baseUrl = "https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/{0}?&auth=temp12345=&{1}";

        #region PROJECTS
        public static List<Models.Project> GetAllProjects()
        {
            string requestUrl = string.Format(baseUrl, "projects", "&per_page=200");

            var resultString = RestClient.makeAPICall(requestUrl);
            var resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultString);

            List<Models.Project> projects = new List<Models.Project>();

            foreach (var project in resultObject.data)
            {
                projects.Add(project);
            }
            return projects;
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

RESTClient.cs:

```
namespace MVCProject1
{
    public static class RestClient
    {
        public static string makeAPICall(string requestUrl)
        {
            var syncClient = new WebClient();
            var content = syncClient.DownloadString(requestUrl);
            Trace.WriteLine(content.ToString());
            return content;
        }
    }

}
```

[Image of error I'm receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ1pX.png)

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: Include the details of the error in your question, not a part image of it.

Comment: Error I'm receiving: An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MVCProject1.Models.Project>.List(int)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have an issue with deserialization of product list.
Try

```
var projects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.Project>>(resultString);
```

instead of

```
var resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultString);

List<Models.Project> projects = new List<Models.Project>();

foreach (var project in resultObject.data)
{
    projects.Add(project);
}
```

and check that `projects` value is not null and no errors occures while deserialization

Comment: I will try this out! I guess my only concern, and one I didn't describe above is that the actual "project(s)" within the json that will align with the project model is underneath the data object in the json response. See this example respones [link]http://i.imgur.com/6g7r7Xr.png